# NodeJS Request-promise ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID

Tags: node.js, request-promise

When attempting to send a request to a website using HTTPS I receive the following error: ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID

I have attempted adding `insecure: true` to my request payload however this does nothing, I have also tried adding `rejectUnauthorized: false` but this gives me a 400 error - bad request.

```
var rp = require('request-promise').defaults({jar: true});
var sess = rp.jar();

function SendRequest() {
  let link = "https://www.example.com";
  payload = {
    method: 'GET',
    jar: sess,
    json: true,
    url: link,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Host': link,
      'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', // removed this nothing changed
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Mobile Safari/537.36'
    },
    gzip: true
    // tried adding insecure: true (did nothing) & rejectUnauthorized: false (returned 400 error)
  }
  rp(payload)
    .then(function(json) {
      console.log(json)
    })
  }
```

I am expecting for the request to go through without any problems.

Comment: Have you tried setting `npm config set strict-ssl false`? Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Yes I use a firewall and npm config set strict-ssl false did not do anything

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the 400 error was actually with the header, `'Host': link,` and upon removing this and adding `rejectUnauthorized: false` back everything worked.